# Servlet Not Showing Blank Page In Eclispse IDLE

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I just started to learn about JSP and Servlet Please Help Me While Iam running the servlet file it is working but not when I am calling it with html file first my html then servlet then xml
I am new to jsp and servlet so ....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="myservlet">
        <input type="submit" value="GO To Servlet">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class myservlet
 */
public class myservlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public myservlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("Hello");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}

<web-app id="WebApp_ID">
    <display-name>demo1</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>myservlet</display-name>
        <description></description>
        <servlet-class>myservlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>demo.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please provide your `web.xml` and the logs of your webapp container.

Answer (score 0):

use bellow code in your web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">


  </web-app>
```

and  use package and in `<servlet-class>myservlet</servlet-class>`

use use bellow sample code into servlet class

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp");  // redirect page 
        rs.include(request, response);
        out.println("hello");
        out.close();
```